# Update quantity with ajax only first one quantity is working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**The only first quantity is updating when I click on second update button it also gives the same update_id as first update button but in inspect it has different id.
I have a little knowledge about Ajax please suggest an easy way to do that.**

[cart-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVVLD.png)

cart.php

this is cart form this I send a request to actions.php it brings data from actions.php data is coming but only first quantity is working a cart is updating and database is updated but only first one it is not picking the second update button is showing same update id as the first button I think there is a little problem in it.

```
  <!-- Shoping Cart -->
        <div id="products">

        <div class="m-l-25 m-r--38 m-lr-0-xl" id="cart_msg">
        <!--Cart Message--> 
        </div>

        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
$('.overlay').show();
    $.ajax({
        url : "actions.php",
        method : "POST",
        data : {checkOutDetails:1},
        success : function(data){
            $('.overlay').hide();
            $("#products").html(data);

        }
    })

    // =================================================

    $("body").delegate(".update","click",function(event){
        var update = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        var update_id = update.find(".update").attr("update_id");
        var qty = update.find(".qty").val();
        $.ajax({
            url :   "actions.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {updateCartItem:1,update_id:update_id,qty:qty},

            success :   function(data){
                $("#cart_msg").html(data);


        }
    })
    })


    })

</script>
```

actions.php

```
<?php
    include 'include/db.php';
    include 'cssFiles.php';

    function getRealIpAddr()

    {
        if ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) )
        {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) )
        //to check ip passed from proxy
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }

    if (isset($_POST["checkOutDetails"])) {

        echo'<form class="bg0 p-t-75 p-b-85" >
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-xl-7 m-lr-auto m-b-50">
        <div class="m-l-25 m-r--38 m-lr-0-xl">

        <div class="wrap-table-shopping-cart">

        <table class="table-shopping-cart" >
        <tr class="table_head">
                <th class="column-1">Product</th>
                <th class="column-2"></th>
                <th class="column-3">Price</th>
                <th class="column-4">Quantity</th>
                <th class="column-5">Total</th>
                <th colspan="2"  style="text-align: center;" class="column-6">Action</th>

                </tr>
                ';

        $ip_add= getRealIpAddr();

        $total=0;

        $ip_add_query="select * from cart where ip_add='$ip_add'";
        $result=mysqli_query(
            $conn,$ip_add_query);
        $temp="";

        while ($ip_rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $pro_id=$ip_rows['id'];
            $qty=$ip_rows['qty'];
            $get_id_query="select * from product where id='$pro_id'";
            $run_query=mysqli_query(
                $conn,$get_id_query);

            while ($p_info=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {

                $pro_price=array($p_info['price']);
                $p_info['name'];
                $p_info['img1'];
                $p_info['price'];
                $p_id=$p_info['id'];

                $sum_price=array_sum($pro_price);

                $total +=$sum_price;


                echo'

                <tr class="table_row">
                <td class="column-1">
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="'.$p_id.'"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="" value="'.$pro_id.'"/>
                <div class="how-itemcart1">
                <img src="admin/img/'. $p_info['img1'].'" alt="IMG">
                </div>
                </td>
                <td class="column-2">'. $p_info['name'].'</td>
                <td class="column-3">"$"'.$p_info['price'].'</td>
                <td class="column-4">
                <div class="wrap-num-product flex-w m-l-auto m-r-0">
                <div class="btn-num-product-down cl8 hov-btn3 trans-04 flex-c-m">
                <i class="fs-16 zmdi zmdi-minus"></i>
                </div>

                <input class="mtext-104 cl3 txt-center num-product qty" type="number"  value="'.$qty.'">

                <div class="btn-num-product-up cl8 hov-btn3 trans-04 flex-c-m">
                <i class="fs-16 zmdi zmdi-plus"></i>
                </div>
                </div>
                </td>
                <td class="column-5">$ 36.00</td>
                <td class="column-6">
                <a href="#" update_id="'.$pro_id.'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm update">Update</a>

                </td>

                </tr>';     
            }}

            echo'</table>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-w flex-sb-m bor15 p-t-18 p-b-15 p-lr-40 p-lr-15-sm">
            <div class="flex-w flex-m m-r-20 m-tb-5">
            <input class="stext-104 cl2 plh4 size-117 bor13 p-lr-20 m-r-10 m-tb-5" type="text" name="coupon" placeholder="Coupon Code">

            <div class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl2 size-118 bg8 bor13 hov-btn3 p-lr-15 trans-04 pointer m-tb-5">
            Apply coupon
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- <button class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl2 size-119 bg8 bor13 hov-btn3 p-lr-15 trans-04 pointer m-tb-10" type="submit" name="submit">
            Update Cart
            </button> -->
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-7 col-xl-5 m-lr-auto m-b-50">
            <div class="bor10 p-lr-40 p-t-30 p-b-40 m-l-63 m-r-40 m-lr-0-xl p-lr-15-sm">
            <h4 class="mtext-109 cl2 p-b-30">
            Cart Totals
            </h4>

            <div class="flex-w flex-t bor12 p-b-13">
            <div class="size-208">
            <span class="stext-110 cl2">
            Subtotal: 
            </span>
            </div>

            <div class="size-209">
            <span class="mtext-110 cl2">
            $79.65
            </span>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-w flex-t bor12 p-t-15 p-b-30">
            <div class="size-208 w-full-ssm">
            <span class="stext-110 cl2">
            Shipping:
            </span>
            </div>

            <div class="size-209 p-r-18 p-r-0-sm w-full-ssm">
            <p class="stext-111 cl6 p-t-2">
            There are no shipping methods available. Please double check your address, or contact us if you need any help.
            </p>

            <div class="p-t-15">
            <span class="stext-112 cl8">
            Calculate Shipping
            </span>

            <div class="rs1-select2 rs2-select2 bor8 bg0 m-b-12 m-t-9">
            <select class="js-select2" name="time">
            <option>Select a country...</option>
            <option>USA</option>
            <option>UK</option>
            </select>
            <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="bor8 bg0 m-b-12">
            <input class="stext-111 cl8 plh3 size-111 p-lr-15" type="text" name="state" placeholder="State /  country">
            </div>

            <div class="bor8 bg0 m-b-22">
            <input class="stext-111 cl8 plh3 size-111 p-lr-15" type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode / Zip">
            </div>

            <div class="flex-w">
            <div class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl2 size-115 bg8 bor13 hov-btn3 p-lr-15 trans-04 pointer">
            Update Totals
            </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-w flex-t p-t-27 p-b-33">
            <div class="size-208">
            <span class="mtext-101 cl2">
            Total: 
            </span>
            </div>

            <div class="size-209 p-t-1">
            <span class="mtext-110 cl2">
                "$".'.$total.'
        </span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <button class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-116 bg3 bor14 hov-btn3 p-lr-15 trans-04 pointer">
        Proceed to Checkout
    </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>';


    }


    if (isset($_POST["updateCartItem"])) {

    $ip_add= getRealIpAddr();
    $update_id = $_POST["update_id"];
    $qty = $_POST["qty"];

    $sql = "UPDATE cart SET qty='$qty' WHERE id='$update_id' AND ip_add = '$ip_add'";

    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>
        <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
        <b>Product is updated</b>
    </div>";
    exit();
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> var update = $(this).parent().parent().parent();

Looks like you are going up one level too much here? The parent of the update link is `td`, parent of that is the `tr`, parent of that is the full `table`.

So `update.find(".update").attr(...)` will only work on the first `.update` element it finds in the whole table.

Comment: is there any easy way to take unique id of buttton and input to make a query

Answer (score 0):

cart.php

```
    <input class="mtext-104 cl3 txt-center num-product qty" type="number" id="qty'.$pro_id.'"  value="'.$qty.'">

    <a href="#" onclick="test('.$pro_id.')" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm update">Update</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function test(data){
         var temp="#qty"+data;
        var Qty=$(temp).val();

        $.ajax({
            url :   "actions.php",
            method  :   "POST",
            data    :   {update:1,qty:Qty,update_id:data},

            success :   function(data){


            }
        })

    }

</script>
```

actions.php

```
if (isset($_POST["update"])) {  
$ip_add= getRealIpAddr();
$update_id = $_POST["update_id"];
$qty = $_POST["qty"];

$sql = "UPDATE cart SET qty='$qty' WHERE id='$update_id' AND ip_add = '$ip_add'";

if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>
    <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
    <b>Product is updated</b>
</div>";
}
}
```